# Java Swing Video Player

Tags: java, swing, video, media-player

I need a video player in Java that opens File browser when started and than opens a selected video file in Swing/Gui window. I have searched allot and wasnt able to find a working one. I did find something like the code posted here but i couldnt start it because it says that Player cannot be resolved to a type , it doesnt recognice  ControllerListener and so on... If I can get a code source for a simple video player or some help i would be really thankful.

```
package program;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MediaPlayerDemo extends JFrame 
{
     private Player player;
     private File file;

     public MediaPlayerDemo()
     {
         super( "Demonstrating the Java Media Player" );

         JButton openFile = new JButton( "Open file to play" );
         openFile.addActionListener( new ActionListener() 
         {
             public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
             {
                 openFile();
                 createPlayer();
             }
         });
         getContentPane().add( openFile, BorderLayout.NORTH );

         setSize( 300, 300 );
         show();
     }

     private void openFile()
     {
         JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

         fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode( JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY );
         int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog( this );

         // user clicked Cancel button on dialog
         if ( result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION )
             file = null;
         else
             file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
     }

     private void createPlayer()
     {
         if ( file == null )
             return;

         removePreviousPlayer();

         try 
         {
             // create a new player and add listener
             player = Manager.createPlayer( file.toURL() );
             player.addControllerListener( new EventHandler() );
             player.start(); // start player
         }
         catch ( Exception e )
         {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, "Invalid file or location", "Error loading file",
             JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
         }
     }

     private void removePreviousPlayer()
     {
         if ( player == null )
             return;

         player.close();

         Component visual = player.getVisualComponent();
         Component control = player.getControlPanelComponent();

         Container c = getContentPane();

         if ( visual != null )
             c.remove( visual );

         if ( control != null )
             c.remove( control );
     }

     public static void main(String args[])
     {
         MediaPlayerDemo app = new MediaPlayerDemo();

         app.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() 
         {
             public void windowClosing( WindowEvent e )
             {
                 System.exit(0);
             }
         });
     }

     // inner class to handler events from media player
     private class EventHandler implements ControllerListener 
     {
         public void controllerUpdate( ControllerEvent e ) 
         {
             if ( e instanceof RealizeCompleteEvent ) 
             {
                 Container c = getContentPane();

                 // load Visual and Control components if they exist
                 Component visualComponent = player.getVisualComponent();

                 if ( visualComponent != null )
                     c.add( visualComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER );

                 Component controlsComponent = player.getControlPanelComponent();

                 if ( controlsComponent != null )
                     c.add( controlsComponent, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

                 c.doLayout();
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: you need to have the [java tv api](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cdc/opt-pkgs/api/jsr927/javax/media/package-summary.html) in your project imported. take a look at the api und you will see that there are your missing classes and interfaces

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). The example above neither defines nor imports either the `Player` or `Manager` classes. 2) *"I have searched allot and wasnt able to find a working one."* There are a number of Swing based video APIs. List list the ones you found, and be specific about why they did not work for you. Doing that helps people to help you! 3) But in more recent times, I'd recommend looking to the Java-FX based player. I've had good experiences with it for playing audio files (music).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JFM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html) Java Media Framework, in which you can open and play the video